# Queue filling with the same value

Tags: c#, game-development

why does my game not create a snake tail? It just makes a queue filled with the same position.
I think it should make a long snake because removeTai bool is false but it just creates a queue with positions that has the same x and  y

```c#
public void GameTick(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!isGameOver)
            {
                //Clear the board of snake and apple
                board.ClearSnake(snake);
                board.ClearApple(apple);

                snake.Move(direction, false);

                //Draw the snake and the apple again
                board.DrawApple(apple);
                board.DrawSnake(snake);
            }
        }
```

```c#
public void Move(Direction dir, bool removeTail)
        {
            Position pos = Utils.MovePos(positions.Last(), dir);

            positions.Enqueue(pos);

            if(removeTail)
            {
                positions.Dequeue();
            }
        }
```

```c#
public static Position MovePos(Position pos, Direction direction)
            {
                switch (direction)
                {
                    case Direction.Left:
                        pos.x -= 1;
                        break;
                    case Direction.Right:
                        pos.x += 1;
                        break;
                    case Direction.Up:
                        pos.y -= 1;
                        break;
                    case Direction.Down:
                        pos.y += 1;
                        break;
                }
                return pos;
            }
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data? What does `positions` contain before you call move, and what does it look like after? Which `direction` are you calling it with?

Comment: Before: https://snipboard.io/NWCLxD.jpg
After: https://snipboard.io/LXGSAM.jpg

It's also very weird when I step through the code it goes up and down randomly. Is that just because of the timer?

Comment: Is it my snake class there is something wrong with?
https://pastebin.com/K3YGzgR2

Comment: Please show the definition of the `Position` struct.

Answer (score 0):

If `Position` is a reference type (eg; class or record) then you're constantly using the same instance and simply updating its `x` or `y` property and repeatedly enqueuing that same object over and over again while changing the `x` or `y` property for every item in the queue (since they're all the same object).  For each new position, create a new object:

```
// not really moving position now, it's creating the next position
public static Position MovePos( Position origin, Direction direction )
{
    var translatedPos = new Position( origin.x, origin.y );

    switch( direction )
    {
        case Direction.Left:
            translatedPos.x -= 1;
            break;
        // rest of cases
        // also add `default` case to throw an exception
        //   to catch any future unhandled values
    }

    return translatedPos;
}
```

You can also substitute `class` for `struct` (value type) which is copied so the same "item" is not used when changing property values or enqueuing.  A `readonly record` would also be useful as it forces you to create a new instance whenever you want to change a property value with additional useful features like the `with` syntax which makes creating a new instance with a single property change easier. It also uses value equality for comparison, which seems appropriate for your use case.

I suggest you read about reference and value types and how they are passed to methods